# Sending data form thread to jsp page as the data is produced

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

Here is the part of a thread that is producing the text data

```
public void run()
{
    try {

        Elements headlines = doc.select("div.siteContent a");

        for(Element e:headlines)
        {

            String url=e.attr("abs:href");
            Document docs=null;
            try {
             docs=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to "+url);
            }
            if(docs!=null)
            {
            Elements stories=docs.select("div[id=storydetailarea]");
            for(Element s: stories)
            {
                System.out.println(s.text());    // this is text data that i want to send....

            }
            }


        }

        //Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I want that the data produced by this thread should go to the Text area in jsp page until the thread stops...
I have a servlets to start to the thread as submit button is clicked....

```
 <form action="thread" method="post">
    Submit to crawl news from <input type=submit value=submit >
    Headline Stories
    <textarea rows="50" cols="80">  <textarea>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a websocket or maybe ajax

Comment: ok... if i use ajax then what will be the logic.... plz tell me little bit about the logic that i should use....